# Gmail API - Oauth2/google: no credentials found (Golang)

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, imap, gmail-api, service-accounts

​Hello All,
Wanted to do server-side integration for Gmail API. The basic need is using enabling Gmail API I want to read my Gmail inbox for some analytics purpose.

Golang Package - **"google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1"**

As per documentation, I have followed the below steps.

1. New Signed up with Gmail
2. Added billing details to use GCP services
3. Created test project
4. Enabled Gmail API
5. Created Service Account and key inside it. Got credentials.json file
6. On the backend side, I am using the Golang package to extract the
   Gmail inbox.
7. After successful integration, I am trying to run my code but getting
   the below error

   ```
   {"level":"error","msg":"Error while creating gmail service : oauth2/google: no credentials found","time":"2021-07-25T15:11:23+05:30"}
   ```

**Can anyone help me to figure out what is missing?**

Comment: In your question put your code you are trying to run

Comment: To reproduce this, I would need to sign up to GCP, create a service account, install "the golang package", whatever that is, and write code with the same bug. That's out of scope for a Stack Overflow, so I'll vote to close, the only question is which of several applicable close reasons.

Comment: There are multiple ways to authenticate your client to access apis. You'll need to add code related to the method you choose. And update other factors accordingly so that this can be debugged. As @amt mentioned, it is not possible to go ahead with this info in hand.

Comment: Add the code you are using here. See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I currently use OAuth with YouTube and the device flow [1], so maybe this can be helpful. First you need to make a one time request like this:

```
data := url.Values{
   "client_id": {"something.apps.googleusercontent.com"},
   "scope": {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"},
}
res, err := http.PostForm("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code", data)
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
type OAuth struct {
   Device_Code string
   User_Code string
   Verification_URL string
}
```

which you can do a one time prompt to user like this:

```
1. Go to
https://www.google.com/device

2. Enter this code
HNDN-ZWBL

3. Sign in to your Google Account
```

Then, after user log in, you can do an exchange request like this:

```
data := url.Values{
   "client_id": {"something.apps.googleusercontent.com"},
   "client_secret": {"super secret"},
   "device_code": {"device code from above"},
   "grant_type":  {"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"},
}
res, err := http.PostForm("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", data)
```

This will give you an `access_token` and `refresh_token`, that you can save locally for reuse. In addition to "device flow", you also have "native app" flow [2], but I found the former to be a simpler process.

1. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices
2. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app